# Links render as huge empty boxes in iPhones

Tags: html, css, ios

I've just had a complaint from a customer who recently purchased an iPhone in place of her old Android phone: the links on the website I built for her appear as huge empty boxes.

This is [her website](http://westownchiropractic.com).

Here are some screen shots she sent me that illustrate the problem: 
[image: first picture]
[image: second picture]
[image]

She told me that she's had friends with (various models of) iPhones see if they were getting the same behaviour and they all get the same thing: big empty boxes where the links should be.

I don't have an iPhone myself and don't typically test my sites on iPhones, mostly because I've never heard a single complaint from an iPhone user. Naturally, I'm re-assessing that approach!

I've done some general googling and I've also searched here at Stack Overflow but found nothing specific about issues with links in iPhones. I'm surprised that this doesn't seem to be a well-known problem with known solutions. Or maybe my searching skills aren't what I thought they were.

Can anyone suggest why I'm getting this huge empty boxes and how to make them render as proper links, just like they do in my Windows laptop and Android phone? A solution that works on all current/popular versions of iPhone would be ideal. Feel free to examine my code in your browsers but I don't think I'm doing anything too exotic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is visible in Safari, not just on an iPhone. It is related to this bit of css:

```
  a::before {
    content: url("../images/link-white_16x16.jpg") " ";
  }
```

The image does not exist and the resulting URL takes you to a domain parking page. I guess Safari is just putting in the square because the image does not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much, Brian! I've commented that selector out for now and am awaiting my customer's email telling me what happened when she tested it. The file in question isn't even in my IDE so I'm not surprised it's absence is a problem. (I must have renamed it and forgotten to fix it in the CSS.) I'm just surprised that its absence isn't a problem for Windows or Android!

Comment: Good news: my customer tells me that the site looks perfect now! She's absolutely delighted. Thanks again, Bryan! (Sorry for misspelling your name in my first comment!)

Comment: @Henry I’d imagine that image is a little icon to indicate a link. I’m glad it’s sorted and you have a happy customer :)  Please would you accept my answer, thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's right, it was an icon giving the visitor an indication that they were looking at an icon. I've also accepted your answer; I  meant to do that last night before I went to bed but completely forgot!